# How to list all scenes, objects, sensors, controllers, actuators, etc

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Can I assign a module to an empty or an object in my scene and when I run it to be able to define all the scenes, all their objects, all their sensors, their controllers and their actuators?

If yes, how? and if not, why?

thanks.

Comment: do you want to just access them ?

Comment: I wanted to set them all to variables so I can access them in any given time. And make it as automated as possible.I managed it not exactly as I originaly thought(I did not set the script to a cube). Gonna post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bge
import bpy
import sys

def initialization(name):
    """
    The function "initialization" is responsible for:
    1.Loading all scenes.
    2.Setting all scene objects, object sensors and object actuators to variables with corresponding(where the dot "." is replaced with "_").
    These variables are created into the function but are for global use. 
    3.The variable "cont" is created with its content being the controller.
    """ 
    sys.modules[name].cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    for s in bpy.data.scenes.keys():
        bge.logic.addScene(s)
    for scene in bge.logic.getSceneList():
        for obj in scene.objects:
            exec("sys.modules[\"%s\"].%s=scene.objects[\"%s\"]"%(name,str(obj).replace(".","_"),obj))
            for sensor in obj.sensors:
                exec("sys.modules[\"%s\"].%s_%s= obj.sensors[\"%s\"]"%(name,str(obj).replace(".","_"),str(sensor).replace(".","_"),sensor))
    for act in sys.modules[name].cont.actuators:
        exec("sys.modules[\"%s\"].%s=sys.modules[\"%s\"].cont.actuators[\"%s\"]"%(name,str(act).replace(".","_"),name,act))
```

So,this is a module(with the name "Initialization.py" that I have saved in the same folder with the other modules I use and the .blend file. At the start of each module I want to use I just write this:

```
import bge
from initialization import initialization
initialization(__name__)
```

Now every sensor,object,etc. that I mentioned above can be retrieved and used.

**Edit:**
Ignore these lines :

```
for s in bpy.data.scenes.keys():
    bge.logic.addScene(s)
```

since they won't work in standalone game.On the other hand if you have more than 1 scenes, use [bge.logic.addScene(name, overlay=1)](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bge.logic.html?highlight=addscene#bge.logic.addScene)

Comment: is it `obj`  or `obj.name`  also the other lines

Comment: Since the obj variable is used where a string is expected, it automatically returns a string representation of its name.The same goes for act and sensor variables.

Comment: "Bpy is the blender api. It will not available when you run the blenderplayer without blender." a quote from Monster of blenderartists.I 'll try to find another way or change it to manual, only for the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will list all loaded scenes, objects and thier sensors; controllers and actuators :

```
scenes = bge.logic.getSceneList()
for scene in scenes :
    print("scene : %s"%scene.name)
    for obj in scene.objects :
        print("   object : %s"%obj.name)
        for sensor in obj.sensors :
            print("      sensor : %s"%sensor.name)  
        for cont in obj.controllers :
            print("      controller : %s"%cont.name)      
        for actu in obj.actuators :
            print("      actuator : %s"%actu.name)
```